# row values to column and columns names to values bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, pivot

i'm trying to create a new table that has two columns 'tags' ,'cnt'

'tags' will contain the columns names as values

'cnt' contain the value per origin column

[image: origin table]

[image: Desire table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') tag,
  SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'), r'(.*?)(?:,|$)')) kv
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 8279 all_close, 4 all_open, 1504 only_o, 16785 only_f 
)
SELECT 
  TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') tag,
  SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'), r'(.*?)(?:,|$)')) kv
```

with result

```
Row tag         cnt  
1   all_close   8279     
2   all_open    4    
3   only_o      1504     
4   only_f      16785
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot using arrays:

```
select el.which, el.cnt
from t cross join
     (unnest([struct('ALL_CLOSE' as which, t.all_close as cnt),
              struct('ALL_OPEN' as which, t.all_open as cnt),
              . . .
             ])) u(el)
```